# How to export DataTable to excel but keep the formatting

Tags: c#, excel

I have 2 issues when converting DataTable to excel

1. The date format is messy, for example my original data is '2016-12-31', in excel it became '31-12-16'
2. Excel remove trailing zeroes, for example '01' become '1'

Here's the code

```
MemoryStream result = new MemoryStream();
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(result);

CSVwriter csv = new CSVwriter();
string content = csv.GetFromTable(table);
writer.Write(content);
writer.Flush();

return result;
```

GetFromTable method

```
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
StringBuilder rowstr = new StringBuilder();
string Encloser = "\""

foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows) {
    rowstr.Length = 0;
    foreach (DataColumn col in table.Columns) {
        if (col.Ordinal > 0) {
            rowstr.Append(",");
        }

        object obj = row(table.Columns.IndexOf(col));
        rowstr.Append(Encloser + ToStr(obj) + Encloser);
    }
    if (rowstr.Length > 0) {
        str.AppendLine(rowstr.ToString());
    }
}

return str.ToString();
```

UPDATE:

`str.ToString()` result

```
"Date","Code"
"2016-01-31","01"
"2016-01-31","02"
```

Comment: Have you checked data coming from your table?

Comment: I can confirm that the data coming from my table is correct

Comment: Your output seems to be csv, Can you check data in str.ToString();

Comment: Your output seems perfect. It's excel which is reformatting your data.

Comment: is there any workaround?

Comment: no, i end up using Npoi plugin